# Beginner php curl using post, prints contents of other script instead of response

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to learn how to use curl in php from a tutorial. I have one php script communicating with another. The first script is:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/some_directories/testing.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Hello=World&Foo=Bar&Baz=Wombat");

curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl)
```

And a second 'testing.php' script contains only the php tags and: `var_dump($_POST);`

When I run the first script I get the output: `var_dump($_POST);` instead of the posted values. I'm sure this is something obvious, but I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Are you sure you included `<?php` tags? They're required for the parser to recognize the PHP code inside.

Comment: Both the files do have the php tags. Sorry I should have made it clearer in the message, but I had some trouble getting them to show up.

Comment: Okay. What happens when you try to access the page via your web browser: `http://localhost/some_directories/testing.php`?

Comment: It prints out the contents of the file as well. Maybe it's an apache setup problem?

Comment: adding the comment above, what about adding echo "<br>"; var_dump($_GET); to the second script and then pinging that page with this http://localhost/some_directories/testing.php?Hello=World&Foo=Bar&Baz=Wombat

Comment: @MementoMori: How are you running the first script then?

Comment: @AmalMurali from the commandline. Like 'php firstscript.php'

Comment: things to check: are the files in the same directory? are there any characters at the very beginning of the file that might make the script miss the 'var_dump($_POST);'

Comment: @MementoMori: Load the PHP file via your browser and immediately check the webserver error log (i.e. `var/log/apache2/error.log` if you're on Unix).

Comment: Thanks for your help Amal and others. It was a mistake in the httpd.conf file, loadmodule php5 was commented out. Obviously I should have noticed this earlier but I was running the files from the command line.

Comment: @MementoMori: Why did you accept [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690578/1438393) answer? What you said was suggested in [Eduardo's link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690449/1438393)

Comment: @AmalMurali Switched it up. I just wanted to mark something to make sure more people didn't try to answer since I solved it. In all honesty you really deserve the credit. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/some_directories/testing.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Hello=World&Foo=Bar&Baz=Wombat");

$response = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

echo $response;
?>
```

**testing.php**

```
<?php 
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Check this too... if none of your PHP code is running - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/781251

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a true flag for `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Try this instead, its a lot cleaner, and breaks your parameters up a bit

```
$url = 'http://localhost/some_directories/testing.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => http_build_query(array(
                                'Hello' => 'World',
                                'Foo'   => 'Bar',
                                'Baz'   => 'Womabt',
                            )),
));

// error
if (FALSE === ($data = curl_exec($ch)))
{
    print_r(curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```